# PHP variable wont show in form input field

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to select a PHP variable from a database insert it into an html form input. I guess my question is how do you store the query into a variable and then call that variable in an html form? Also, the form is located on a separate page from the form action file. Why is it undefined if it's defined in the PHP file? The desired output is when I load the html page the value from the database for nickname auto-fills that field of the form.

error:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: Nickname in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Client-Projects\Crossfire\templates\CoinSubmission.html** on line **45**

***CoinSubmission.html***

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="AdminCoinSub_Code.php" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="Nickname" id="Nickname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Nickname); ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
```

***AdminCoinSub_Code.php***

```
<?php {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "administrator_logins";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coin (ProfileID, Store, Position, 
        Nickname, ContactNumber, MachineCount, CutOffDate, Coins, location, LastSubmission, Rank) 
        VALUES (:ProfileID, :Store,:Position, :Nickname,:ContactNumber,:MachineCount,:CutOffDate, :Coins,:location,:LastSubmission,:Rank)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':ProfileID', $_POST['ProfileID']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Store', $_POST['Store']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Position', $_POST['Position']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Nickname', $_POST['Nickname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ContactNumber', $_POST['ContactNumber']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':MachineCount', $_POST['MachineCount']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':CutOffDate', $_POST['CutOffDate']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Coins', $_POST['Coins']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $_POST['location']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':LastSubmission', $_POST['LastSubmission']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Rank', $_POST['Rank']);

    $stmt->execute();

      echo "Success";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
}

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT `Nickname` FROM `adminlogin` WHERE `ProfileID` = ':ProfileID'";
$Nickname = $conn->query($query);  // This is where the query is executed
$fetcher = $Nickname->fetch_assoc();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Nickname))
if (mysqli_num_rows($Nickname) > 0) {
    echo 'User name exists in the table.';
} else {
    echo 'User name does not exist in the table.';
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your html page should have the extension **.php** and not **.html**, that way it can interpret your php code inside the html file, don't worry this wont break the html.

> why is it undefined if it's defined in the php file.

It's because each php script run separately unless you hook them together.
I would recommend yo read a bit more about how php works.

For this example to work i would do it it this way.

**CoinSubmission.php**

```
<?php //This goes at the top of the file
 include_once('AdminCoinSub_Code.php') //If they are in the same dir else you will need to set the path properly. 
?>

<form autocomplete="off" action="AdminCoinSub_Code.php" method="POST">
 <p>
  <input type="text" name="Nickname" id="Nickname" value="<?php echo 
   htmlspecialchars($Nickname); ?>">
 </p>
</form>
```

The include at the top will "paste" your code of *AdminCoinSub_Code* in the *CoinSubmission* file and treat it as one file. So the variable will be accesible for it.

Note: My explanation is oversimplified, it ain't exactily how it works, but should get the gist of it.

Alaa Morad answer if also valid, but remember to change the **.html** to **.php**

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$Nickname` will not be set if **Register Globals** is off witch is a normal thing !

> **Register Globals** has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0

so use `$_POST`

```
<input type="text" name="Nickname" id="Nickname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['Nickname']); ?>">
```

Comment: @Dharman Sorry I mean Register Globals : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Configuration:_Register_Globals

Comment: Register globals has been removed from PHP for years, no reason to bring it up. Let it rest in peace. I still don't think this is what they asked about.

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind that OP is sending the POST data to one file and is then trying to get the results in another. This is not a problem with unregistered globals, it is a dire misunderstanding of how PHP variables work.